# Running executables using Windows batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an application in which I would like to run many executables using a batch file (in my case a program called AMDIS, http://chemdata.nist.gov/mass-spc/amdis/downloads/).
On the Windows command prompt it works if I type

```
C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE C:\Users\Ento\Documents\GCMS\test_cataglyphis_iberica\queens\CI23_Q_120828_01.CD‌​F /S /E
```

where AMDIS_32 is the program I want to run and C:\Users\Ento\Documents\GCMS\test_cataglyphis_iberica\queens\CI23_Q_120828_01.CD‌​F the file I want it to analyze and /S /E some opions.

Now I would like to make these calls repeatedly using a batch file in Windows 7.
I tried making a batch file with

```
START C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE C:\Users\Ento\Documents\GCMS\test_cataglyphis_iberica\queens\CI23_Q_120828_01.CD‌​‌​F /S /E
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I should do this?

cheers,
Tom

EDIT: based on the info in forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/fdb993d9-6a9c-4459-aedb-0283f2d6935d I found that my mistake had to do with saving my batch file in UNICODE rather than ANSI encoding - now it works - thanks to you all!!

Comment: In general, I think it's better not to tell everybody on The Internet how your private filesystem is organized. You can make up filenames and directories for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Echo OFF

Set /A "Interval=3"

PUSHD "C:\NIST08\AMDIS32"

:Loop
Start /B AMDIS_32.EXE "C:\Users\Ento\Documents\GCMS\test_cataglyphis_iberica\queens\CI23_Q_120828_01.CD‌​F" /S /E
Ping -n %INTERVAL% Localhost >NUL
Goto :Loop
```

Comment: Why not `timeout /t %INTERVAL%` ?

Comment: because Timeout is a command of Win7/Vista only, we don't know the OS of the OP

Comment: Well the strange thing is that if I save Start /B "" "C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE" "C:\Users\Ento\Documents\GCMS\test_cataglyphis_iberica\queens\CI23_Q_120828_01.CD‌​F" /S /E in a .bat file and then double click on it that I just get a very brief command prompt window popping up that then disappears but it doesn't do anything. If I type it directly on the command prompt it works though. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Tom try my update, the code before and after the update worked, just ensure if you don't want to use the "/B" parametter of the Start command to stop the execution of the script.

Comment: Well the bizarre thing is that even Start "C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE" saved in a .bat file won't run for some reason, even though it works if I type C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE at the Windows command prompt (I'm using Win7). Any thoughts? I'm sure it must be something silly... You can download this AMDIS program from here, http://chemdata.nist.gov/mass-spc/amdis/downloads/, if you would like to try for yourself...

Comment: Don't type Start "C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE" with double quotes if the path don't have spaces, before my last edit I typed this: Start /B "" "C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE" , you said don't worked but you've tested?, that worked. Also you can simply write "C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE", without START and WITHOUT double quotes.

Comment: Yes sorry - it did work! I just messed up by accidentally saving my batch file in UNICODE rather than ANSI encoding, as a result of copying and pasting from another program... Sorry for all the hassle, but now it works!!

Answer (score 3):

```
:X
C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE C:\Users\Ento\Documents\GCMS\test_cataglyphis_iberica\queens\CI23_Q_120828_01.CD‌​F /S /E
goto X
```

Comment: Well the strange thing is that if I type C:\NIST08\AMDIS32\AMDIS_32.EXE C:\Users\Ento\Documents\GCMS\test_cataglyphis_iberica\queens\CI23_Q_120828_01.C‌​D‌​F /S /E directly on the command prompt that it works, but when I save it in a .bat file and then double click on it I just get a very brief command prompt window popping up that then disappears but it doesn't do anything. Any thoughts?